# How can I use KingFisher library for images that are in assets folder, Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, assets, kingfisher

I am using king fisher library but my problem is that I can't use this for images that stored in the asset- all of the kingfisher methods need url, so how can I use this for assets?

Comment: Kingfisher library is used to download image from web and store it in cache. It reduces the network usage and allows the app to reuse when it is needed to load same image multiple times. There is no need to use suck libraries for asset images.

Comment: KingFisher is a library used to manage downloading and caching *remote* images. it is not designed for local images and not needed. just use UIImage(named: "whatever") for assets

Comment: I know how to use local files but I wanted to use king fisher filters for that images so I can't use king fisher for assets right?

Comment: I assume you could point to an image using local URL, but since assets are stored specifically, I don't think you'll be able to do that - check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769092/can-i-get-a-nsurl-from-an-xcassets-bundle

Comment: What "filters" are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I want to dark my Image look like when you put a view infront of the photo and make that black and change the alpha or opacity of that to 0.5

Answer (score 8):

Those who are saying in the comments that we don't need to load local Image from Assets through kingfisher for them, there is a scenario, for example when we are loading images in UITableView and under if condition we load image from remote URL and in else condition, we load from local assets. In that scenario, if we directly assign an image with `UIImage(...)` method, TableView images will start behaving abnormally. So we need to inform to Kingfisher that we have directly changed the image and don't update it when it's loaded from the remote URL.
For this kind of scenario, you can use the following code

```
import Kingfisher

 //////// In your cellForRowAt method

if (loadThroughRemoteURL) {
    cell.imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: "YOUR_REMOTE_IMAGE_URL"))
} 
else { // loading through local assets
       let resource: Resource? = nil
       cell.imageView.kf.setImage(with: resource) // inform kingfisher that you are assigning this image by your own
       cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "your_image_in_assets")
}
```

Comment: Another reason to use Kingfisher would be if you want to load a WebP image from Assets. A feature that Xcode doesn't natively support.