# Correct way to initialize URL() with a named asset in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use the Vision framework with some images in my assets folder, but I'm struggling with initializing the URL that I need for the request handler:

```
let imageUrl = URL(what to put here?)
let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(url: imageUrl)
```

I can easily instantiate `UIImage` using `UIImage(named: imageName)` but there is no `URL(named: imageName)` and I can't figure out what I should use instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VNImageRequestHandler` also has an [initialiser that accepts a `CGImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnimagerequesthandler/2866541-init), use that instead.

```
VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: UIImage(named: "...").cgImage!)
```

Outside the context of `VNImageRequestHandler`, [getting the URL from an image in the assets does not seem possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769092/can-i-get-a-nsurl-from-an-xcassets-bundle).